# sprintf とは何か

Tags: c++, c

以下のプログラム中の`sprintf`はどのような働きでしょうか？

```c
if(p >= 10000 ){
    sprintf(str,"D:\\○○研_生産情報特別実験_中山_引継ぎ\\System\\Final\\講義中の教師の動作の推定と記録を行うシステム\\OpenCV-Sample001\\講義画像\\cap%05d.bmp",p);
}else{
    sprintf(str,"D:\\○○研_生産情報特別実験_中山_引継ぎ\\System\\Final\\講義中の教師の動作の推定と記録を行うシステム\\OpenCV-Sample001\\講義画像\\cap%04d.bmp",p);
}
```

Comment: このプログラムはどの「言語」で書かれたものでしょうか？タグ付けされた`visual-studio`や`opencv`の要素は質問中に出てこないので、プログラミング言語についての説明をしてもらった方が正確な回答が付きやすいと思います。 (質問は後からでも [編集] できます)

Answer (score 4):

([opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) かつ [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) だと言語は [c](/questions/tagged/c) または [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) とみなせそう)
[c](/questions/tagged/c) の `sprintf` は `char` の配列に書式展開した文字列を出力する関数です。
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ybk95axf.aspx (機械翻訳)
https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man3/printf.3.html
(こっちのほうが読みやすいはず)

提示コード中の `str` は `char str[_MAX_PATH];` のように定義されている `char` の配列であるはずです。
`sprintf` はそこに `D:\○○研_生産情報特別実験_中山_引継ぎ\System\Final\講義中の教師の動作の推定と記録を行うシステム\OpenCV-Sample001\講義画像\cap12345.bmp` のように文字列を書式展開して（この例では `%d` が対応する数値を表記する複数文字に展開される）保存します。
ソースコード中のバックスラッシュはコンパイル時にエスケープ展開されることに注意。

Comment: 返信遅くなり申し訳ありません。**sprintf はそこに D:\○○研_生産情報特別実験_中山_引継ぎ\System\Final\講義中の教師の動作の推定と記録を行うシステム\OpenCV-Sample001\講義画像\cap12345.bmp のように文字列を書式展開して（この例では %d が対応する数値を表記する複数文字に展開される）保存します。**

Comment: とは、`D:\○○研_生産情報特別実験_中山_引継ぎ\System\Final\講義中の教師の動作の推定と記録を行うシステム\OpenCV-Sample001\講義画像\cap12345.bmp`自体を文字列として保存するということですか？

Comment: はいそうです。 `str` にそういう文字列が保存されるので、おそらく引き続き `fopen` に渡してビットマップファイルを読み込んでるんでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

774RRさんがすでに詳細に回答されていますが、初心者向けの説明をすると

「変数に格納されている値、文字列なども組み合わせて、新しい文字列を作成する」

という用途でよく使用します。

Comment: それは、画像データの他にパス自体も文字列として保存するということでしょうか？

Comment: 774RRさんの回答と重複しますが、画像データーを出力したパスを、プログラム内部の文字列変数にして、それをプログラムのそれ以降の箇所で、画像ファイルを開くためのファイル名変数として使っているのではないでしょうか？続くソースに、ビットマップファイルを開く、`? = fopen(str, "rb");`の様な行が有るのだと思います